# Return MYSQL results based on a sub query count?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to adjust the following MYSQL query so that it only shows results where the video count is greater than 0? I have tried the following but it doesn't recognise

> video_count

```
SELECT channels.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos WHERE videos.video_publisher_id = channels.channel_id) as `video_count` 
FROM channels 
WHERE  channel_active = 1
AND video_count > 0
AND channel_thumbnail IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY channel_subscribers DESC
```

Comment: you can used `havin_by` clause

Comment: @NikuNjRathod What, precisely, do you expect `havin_by` to do?

Answer (score 1):

Move your subquery from the `SELECT` clause to the `FROM` clause. An inner join guarantees matches.

```
SELECT c.*, v.video_count
FROM channels c
JOIN
(
  SELECT video_publisher_id, COUNT(*) AS video_count
  FROM videos 
  GROUP BY video_publisher_id
) v ON v.video_publisher_id = c.channel_id
WHERE c.channel_active = 1
  AND c.channel_thumbnail IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c.channel_subscribers DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

For filter by subquery result or aggregation function value you can use `HAVING`. You have error in `WHERE` clause because MySQL don't know about this column in `WHERE`

[image]

```
SELECT channels.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos WHERE videos.video_publisher_id = channels.channel_id) as `video_count` 
FROM channels 
WHERE  channel_active = 1
AND channel_thumbnail IS NOT NULL
HAVING video_count > 0
ORDER BY channel_subscribers DESC
```

Or:

```
SELECT channels.*, COUNT(*) AS video_count
FROM channels 
INNER JOIN videos 
ON videos.video_publisher_id = channels.channel_id
WHERE  channel_active = 1
AND channel_thumbnail IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY channels.channel_id
ORDER BY channel_subscribers DESC
```

Comment: The execution order is not quite correct; `ORDER BY` comes last. (Otherwise we would never be able to sort by column aliases.) The first query uses a MySQL extension by using a column alias in `HAVING` and is thus non-standard SQL. As `ORDER BY` is the last thing that happens in a query (except for a possible `LIMIT` clause), it should also come last in your query. It looks queer to see the `ORDER BY` clause followed by the `HAVING` clause. If you only want channels with videos, use an inner join and no `HAVING` is required. Outer join only when you want channels without videos, too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you.

```
SELECT channels.*,video_count.count
FROM channels 
left join (SELECT channel_id,COUNT(*) count FROM videos) as `video_count` on video_count.video_publisher_id = channels.channel_id
WHERE  channel_active = 1
AND video_count.count > 0
AND channel_thumbnail IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY channel_subscribers DESC
```